# Which <groupId> to mention for ant-javafx.jar & jfxrt.jar dependency in POM.xml while migrating from Oracle to Zulu Azul Open JDK 1.8 (8.0.302) ?)

Tags: java, maven, javafx, desktop-application, azul-zulu

I am working on Windows Desktop Application which currently uses Oracle JDK 1.8 () version and JavaFX. Our Team is planning to migrate from Oracle JDK 1.8 to Azul Zulu Open JDK 1.8 (8.0.302).
I have changed the path of JAVA_HOME, Installed JREs which points to Zulu JDK Location in my local workspace. I have also changed the JRE path in Run Configuration. After that, when I ran application, it is loading the splash screen, but other screen navigations are taking long time to load.

My 2 doubt here are -

1. **Should I change the groupId value** to some other thing instead of **com.oracle** with below dependencies  ?

   ```
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
                    <artifactId>ant-javafx</artifactId>
                    <version>${javafx.version}</version>
                    <systemPath>${java.home}/../lib/ant- 
                       javafx.jar</systemPath>
                    <scope>system</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javafx</artifactId>
                    <version>${javafx.version}</version>
                 <systemPath>${java.home}/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar</systemPath>
                    <scope>system</scope>
                </dependency>
   ```
2. I observed that Oracle JDK lib folder has deploy folder, but Zulu JDK Lib folder didn't had that deploy folder. So, Is that OK ? or should I
   include/copy deploy folder in lib folder?

Please assist with these two doubts.

Comment: Why not just check on Maven Central?

Comment: I checked it. But, I didn't find which one to replace with **com.oracle**

Comment: tbh I doubt it will matter much. You're currently able to build OK aren't you? I actually can't even find 'ant-javafx' anywhere. Are you using Ant to build?

Comment: Locally, I am able to build the application, Splash screen followed by Home Screen is displayed. After that, navigating to any other screen is taking longer time to display/render.   Build Tool used in **Maven** !  So, I am not sure what other configurations to be done while migrating to Azul Zulu JDK.

Comment: I'm not sure where all this ant- stuff is coming from then if you're using Maven. Check out the docs for Maven building of javafx. I did one a couple of days ago but it looks like it was wiped (if I didn't work in my /tmp folder, I'd need a hard drive the size of the planet)

Comment: **ant-javafx.jar** is fetched from **C:\Program Files\Java\zulu-fx-jdk8.0.302\lib**  But I am also not sure about **ant-javafx** artifactId.

Comment: This is all the wrong way around. The way Maven works is that *it* fetches the dependencies from repositories. The correct deps are done that way. There might be something called 'ant-javafx.jar' on your system but it doesn't have much to do with what you should have in pom.xml

Comment: I've just generated a runnable JavaFX fxml app from a Maven archetype. [This](https://technojeeves.com/tech/javafx-fmxl-pom.xml) is what its pom.xml looks like

Comment: @g00se I think the `ant-javafx` stuff comes from old [JavaFX Ant Tasks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/javafx_ant_tasks.html), which were provided with old JavaFX and Oracle JDK distributions, but have long since been deprecated and replaced by alternative technology.  It is not surprising that such things would not be available in in a Zulu JDK distribution or in Maven central, as some of that technology dates back to when parts of JavaFX were closed source code only distributed by Oracle.

Comment: RIght. I though it must be something ancient ;)